# How to better allocate variables dependable between themselves in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When analysing a dataframe with pandas and python I had this going on:

```
jan = df1["0"] + df1["1"]
feb = jan + df1["2"] - df2["1"]
mar = feb + df1["3"] - df2["2"]
apr = mar + df1["4"] - df2["3"]
may = apr + df1["5"] - df2["4"]
jun = may + df1["6"] - df2["5"]
jul = jun + df1["7"] - df2["6"]
aug = jul + df1["8"] - df2["7"]
sep = aug + df1["9"] - df2["8"]
oct = sep + df1["10"] - df2["9"]
nov = oct + df1["11"] - df2["10"]
dec = nov + df1["12"] - df2["11"]

year = [jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec]
```

Actual values doesn't matter much, they're all integers and the next month is dependent on the result of the previous month. Therefore I need to declare each variable on it's own line, right?

From here, I have two questions:

1. Making the variables on a loop (in case I want to expand the number of variables to n months)
2. The thing I'm more interested about, a way of declaring those variables together even without a proper loop.

How would you guys make this code more clean, better saying, without using n lines to assign n variables? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a list! Everithing in one line:

```
[df1[str(i+1)] - df2[str(i-1) for i in range(12)]
```

then you can manipulate the elements in the list as you like.